# Amplify publish doesn't remove files from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I have an AWS amplify project which deploys static web pages to S3 and CloudFront.

I use `amplify publish --invalidateCloudFront` to deploy changes,
but I found locally deleted files are not removed from S3.

Is there any option to remove deleted files from S3.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/713